# Prove: $A\cap B=\emptyset \implies A\cap B^c=A$[EDITED]

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

**Problem:** $A\cap B=\emptyset \implies A\cap B^c=A$

I have partly done the proof, but I have not idea if I am headed in the right direction. Any help would be appreciated.

Since I know that A∩B is disjoint,
A∩$B^c$ is not disjoint so that
x∈A & x∈$B^c$

so A⊆A∩$B^c$ & A∩$B^c$⊆A
because A∩B' means that A includes all elements in A∩B' and vice versa

Where do I go from this?

Edit: I fixed the title, and found the appropriate symbols. I hope this is enough to receive help, thanks.

Comment: Could you please review your title, and edit it?  As written it is self contradictory unless $A = \varnothing$.  That is, the only possible scenario, is as follows: "$A\cap B = \varnothing$, then $A\cap B = A$ if and only if $A=\varnothing$.

Comment: I assume you mean "show that $A\cap B=\emptyset \implies A\cap B^c=A$" but would it really be so difficult to respond to the people who are asking for clarification?

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice it omitted the compliment symbol above B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've proved that $A \subseteq A \cap B^c$ and $A \cap B^c\subseteq A$ then you're done.

Two sets $C,D$ are equal if they have the same elements: $x \in C \iff x \in D$. This is the same as $C \subseteq D$ and $D \subseteq C$

Comment: A "then" statement, such as in this case where A∩$B^c$=A is similar to saying A⊆A∩$B^c$ ?So if we find from the "if" statement that A⊆A∩$B^c$ we have finished the proof? I thought I was missing something. I was hinted by another online source that a proof by contradiction could be used in proofs, but I got stuck there. Thanks though!